# Is there a name for being totally dependent?

Tags: five-hindrances

During the last days I experienced that I felt total dependent. I was walking from A to B and there was no choice for me to make, neither to stop nor anything else. In fact, I felt like a robot...

Is there a name for this kind of total dependance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the closest real "thing" in Buddhism that touches on what you've described is *thina-middha*, or "sloth and torpor" (one of the Five Hindrances). It's characterized in part by a lack of energy (which can be mental in addition to physical). This isn't necessarily what you shared, but a lack of mental energy could make one feel as if driven by an external force, bound by choices made elsewhere. Only you could really say for sure if that particular hindrance was at play in how you felt.

There is also the Pāli word *upanissayo* which is sometimes translated as "destiny", but is closer in meaning to "basis" or "tendency". It's as close as you get to the notion of predestination in Pāli. (Again, not what you described, but a word that somewhat connects to the idea.)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Buddhism SE. We have a [Guide](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post?cb=1) and a [Resource tab](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) for new users that you might like. Btw, I think its really good spotted, that this is actually one of the 5 hindrances that are in effect.